# How to catch error "File not loaded completely"

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have a code which opens a text file. It contains a number of rows that is more than the limit of Excel. When manually opening it, there is a prompt that says "File not loaded completely" but when in macro, I don't see a prompt.

What I want to do is to catch that error. Even when the display alerts of my macro is enabled, still no error is caught.

```
 On Error Goto catch_err
 ...open text file here
 On Error Goto 0

 catch_err:
   Msgbox err.description
```

That is the structure of my code.

Comment: Not sure about Excel, but in Access you sometimes need a statement at the top of the code that says; Set Warnings = True.  This turns on any warnings that the app will throw, so they get displayed.

Comment: why don`t you try try catch statements?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you stream the file in and move to the next tab every time you hit 1M rows?

I threw this together for you, excuse the Citrix line in there (I needed it for testing, left it in in case you are on that environment).

```
Sub BigFile()
Dim myFile As String, textline As String, X As Long
'myFile = "\\Client\C$\Temp\YourBigFile.txt" 'Silly Citrix syntax
myFile = "C:\Temp\YourBigFile.txt" 'Normal syntax
Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    X = X + 1
    If X = 1000000 + 1 Then
        Sheets.Add
        X = 1
    End If
    Line Input #1, textline
    Range("A" & X).Formula = textline
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

This way you don't need to test for the error because there won't be one.

Comment: I need it to be faster as much as possible. Opening text file via excel (tab delimited text) with 1M rows would take so much time.

Anyway, I found out a better work around for this. thanks anyway :)